# TCGA pathology slides magnification

Tags: deep-learning

Does anybody know if there is a way to find out what are the magnification levels of the TCGA pathology slides? Are they all 40x? I can't seem to find a label of that anywhere

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you provide a link to any images? It's likely that the resolution is available in the file metadata.

Comment: Thanks. Here is an example of one of them. I can't seem to find the resolution in the metadata

Comment: https://portal.gdc.cancer.gov/files/f23db5f3-6b2e-471e-9b18-e477140d9a5e